# Keyframes not shown

Tags: animation, interface, keyframes

I dont understand why I can insert keyframes, but keyframes not shown and I cant manage my animation in Timeline, in Graph Editor, nowhere. I created new file and it works, but in this file it does not works. May be I turned off them, I dont know

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hover your pointer over the timeline and drag it using the Middle Mouse Button upwards .Maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

In the *Dope Sheet* you've enabled the *Only Show Selected* option, it means you need to select the node to see its keyframes.

Comment: I change it, but keyframes still not shown

Comment: weird because it works on my computer...

Comment: I did this again and its shown in Dope Sheet, but when I open Timeline they again hidden, and in Dope Sheet "Only Show Selected" enables automatically.
Edited: I choose View > Toggle Grah Editor and now it shows in Graph Editor, but in Timeline it is still hidden